# SQL Data Sampling

Tags: sql

We have had a request to provide some data to an external company.
They require only a sample of data, simple right? wrong.

Here is their sampling criteria:

> - Total Number of records divided by 720 (required sample size) - this gives **sampling interval** (if result is a fraction, round down to next whole number).
> - Halve the sampling interval to get the starting point.
> - Return each record by adding on the sampling interval.
>
> EXAMPLE:
>
> - 10,000 Records - Sampling interval = 13 (10,000/720)
> - Starting Point = 6 (13/2 Rounded)
> - Return records 6, 19 (6+13), 32 (19+13), 45 (32+13) etc.....

Please can someone tell me how (if) something like this is possible in SQL.

Comment: What brand of SQL?  If you have ROW_NUMBER() that will help a lot.  Also, having a sampling interval of 720, and a defined starting point ***implies*** the data has an order - So, in what order should your data appear?

Comment: ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by TransactionDate) AS RowNumber,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have use of ROW_NUMBER(), then you can do this relatively easily.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a, b, c, d) AS record_id,
    *
  FROM
    yourTable
)
  AS data
WHERE
  (record_id + 360) % 720 = 0
```

`ROW_NUMBER()` gives all your data a sequential identifier (this is important as the id field must both be unique and NOT have ANY gaps).  It also defines the order you want the data in `(ORDER BY a, b, c, d)`.

With that id, if you use Modulo (Often the `%` operator), you can test if the record is the 720th record, 1440th record, etc (because 720 % 720 = 0).

Then, if you offset your id value by 360, you can change the starting point of your result set.

**EDIT**

After re-reading the question, I see you don't want every 720th record, but uniformly selected 720 records.

As such, replace `720` with `(SELECT COUNT(*) / 720 FROM yourTable)`

And replace `360` with `(SELECT (COUNT(*) / 720) / 2 FROM yourTable)`

**EDIT**

Ignoring the rounding conditions will allow a result of exactly 720 records.  This requires using non-integer values, and the result of the modulo being less than 1.

```
WHERE
  (record_id + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourTable) / 1440.0)
  %
  ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourTable) / 720.0)
  <
  1.0
```

Comment: OK.So I run my query on the data I have gathered to return - This gives me 9353 records. Sampling interval should be 12, start point should be 6. When I add your code in, I get 779 rows returned, any ideas?

Comment: @Richard - The 779 rows is because of your requirement to round the sample interval down to an integer. `9353 / 720 = 12.99` => `12`. Then, `9353 / 12 = 779.33` => `779`. Do you know which part is most important? Rounding the sample interval down, or returning exactly 720 records?  ***[It's not possible to have both.]***

Comment: From the Data Request, I would say that 720 is the target.

Comment: @Richard - Answer updated to return 720 records rather than implement the requested rounding.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @sample_size int, @starting_point int

select @sample_size = 200

select top (@sample_size) col1, col2, col3, col4 
from (
    select *, row_number() over (order by col1, col2) as row
    from your_table
) t
where  (row   % ((select count(*) from your_table) / @sample_size)) - (select count(*) from your_table) / @sample_size / 2) = 0
```

It's going to work in SQL Server 2005+.

[TOP (@variable)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) is used to limit rows (`where` condition because of integers rounding might not be enough, may return more rows then needed) and [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to number and order rows.

Working example: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/62315/sql-data-sampling below code:

```
declare @tab table (id int identity(1,1), col1 varchar(3), col2 varchar(3))

declare @i int

set @i = 0

while @i <= 1000
begin
  insert into @tab
  select 'aaa', 'bbb'
  set @i = @i+1
end

declare @sample_size int

select @sample_size = 123

select ((select count(*) from @tab) / @sample_size) as sample_interval

select top (@sample_size) *
from (
    select *, row_number() over (order by col1, col2, id desc) as row
    from @tab
) t
where  (row   % ((select count(*) from @tab) / @sample_size)) - ((select count(*) from @tab) / @sample_size / 2) = 0
```

Comment: I wonder why "-1", could you explain? maybe I learn something new.

Comment: Your solution is good, but the reason I -1 is that it is not a dynamic approach. The SP should really calculate the starting point itself.

Answer (score 0):

SQL server has in-built function for it.

SELECT FirstName, LastName
FROM Person.Person 
TABLESAMPLE (10 PERCENT) ;

Answer (score -1):

You can use rank  to get a row-number. The following code will create 10000 records in a table, then select the 6th, 19th, 32nd, etc, for a total of 769 rows.

```
CREATE TABLE Tbl (
    Data varchar (255)
)
GO

DECLARE @i int 
SET @i = 0
WHILE (@i < 10000)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Tbl (Data) VALUES (CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()))
    SET @i = @i + 1
END
GO

DECLARE @interval int
DECLARE @start int
DECLARE @total int
SELECT  @total = COUNT(*),
        @start = FLOOR(COUNT(*) / 720) / 2,
        @interval = FLOOR(COUNT(*) / 720)
FROM Tbl

PRINT 'Start record: ' + CAST(@start as varchar(10)) 
PRINT 'Interval: ' + CAST(@interval as varchar(10)) 

SELECT rank, Data
FROM (
    SELECT rank() 
    OVER (ORDER BY t.Data) as rank, t.Data AS Data
    FROM Tbl t) q
WHERE   ((rank + 1) + @start) % @interval = 0
```

Comment: Why RANK()? Where records have the same ranking value this will cause collisions, and multiple values with the same RANK(). This can lead to both over-selection (Multiple values with a RANK() of interest) and under-selection (Missing ranks due to that rank actually being a tie at another position). Just use ROW_NUMBER()?